# Remove default menu options from Add Activity dropdown on Activities tab on Case screen

Tags: acumatica

I want to remove different menu options available such as Add Note, Add Phone Call, Add Work Item, etc. from Add Activity menu on Activities tab on Case screen and add it directly on the toolbar instead of it showing in dropdown.

I know I can add menu option under Actions using below command but not sure how to remove those options including the top level menu. Probably just removing from ASPX code?

```
Base.action.AddMenuAction()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below code snippet.

```cs
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;

namespace PXDemoPkg
{
    public class CRCaseMaintPXDemoExt : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            if (Base.Actions.Contains("NewActivity"))
            {
                PXButtonState actionsMenuState = Base.Actions["NewActivity"].GetState(null) as PXButtonState;
                if (actionsMenuState != null)
                {
                    foreach (ButtonMenu button in actionsMenuState.Menus)
                    {
                        button.Visible = false;
                    }
                    actionsMenuState.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```